# One-Time Customer Discount per Customer Group

Tags: customer, coupon

Hi I wanted to see if I can do some sort of promotional thing on a customer account.

Say customer A is assigned the customer group industry. I want to assign customer A a discount of 20% per item, but it only can be "used" one time. So after the customer purchases that item it returns to normal price. Any idea on how I could do that? I tried looking at plugins but I can't seem to find "that logic"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a shopping cart discount - with or without coupon codes.

You have two requirements:

## 1. "Apply to a customer group "Industry"

A shopping cart promotion can be relegated to a customer group - fulfilling this requirement.

[image]

## 2. "One-time-use"

You'll need to set "Uses per customer" to a value of one:

[image]

Comment: It wouldn't work if there's no coupon code and someone else from the same user group uses the discount before the target user though.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism "per customer" means it's tracked on a per-customer basis. I think this will work.

Comment: Ok I'm kind of unsure as the OP said "on a customer account" it sounds like it's for one single customer

Comment: A single customer in a single group has the same effect, no? @markwang please clarify.

Comment: Yes it does but I'm not sure the said customer is the only one in the group that's why I'm asking ;)

Comment: You're not making sense (maybe let's move to chat?) Any customer not in the NOT LOGGED IN group must have a customer ID. Uses are tracked by customer ID in catalogrule tables.

Comment: Yes so the customer group in my example is "industry". There would be multiple customers. They must be logged in to see "industry" group's pricing. However, I only want to show that discount pricing once. After they've ordered the product (multiple products) the discount would no longer be valid.  Say you have a product that is $100, then you log in and then its $80. After you purchase this $80 product it becomes $100. They aren't entering a code it would be based off of their customer group.  So it would be iterative on all products. Discount by X then after purchase of that product no disc

Comment: @philwinkle you were right it's not about ONE single customer but about the entire group. The "promotional thing on a customer account" sentence was kind of confusing